# Browser will not do a https connection to some sites

Tags: https

I can access a given website with https connection fine on my browser running on an AWS amazon cloud ec2 instance. Problem is when I try to access same site on my physical pc ( all pcs in my home ) I cannot connect via https.  No idea where to start but it is clearly a problem with my network / router as this is the only commonality between all my home pcs.

Comment: Could the two clowns that down voted this question expand a little on why it was downvoted.  Clearly ye know better than the web gurus I have asked at work who have no explanation why I am seeing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Apple-/ or Safaribrowsers?
I had this issue where almost all Safari-users were unable to connect because i added a "Keepalive header". After removing this, those people could connect again.

The setted ciphers might also exclude some browsers.

Check your site on this page https://www.ssllabs.com/ for compatibility.

Comment: No, without making any changes I have noticed that sites I used to use on a regular basis,  from my desktop pc using both Chrome and Firefox, no longer allow me to connect to them using HTTPS. Browser warns me that sites are insecure which is sort of stating the obvious. I can do https fine from my cloud pc so the sites definitely do support https. PS  I do love the down votes this has got as it is such a simple answer that it is not even worth giving a comment as to why these other folks thought it worth downvoting.